# Multiple Matrix subset and store in Array

Tags: arrays, r, subset

I have a matrix H of size (r x c) and I want to subsample this matrix 100 times extracting 100 matrices of size (m x c) and store each of them into an array of dim (m x c x 100).

For random extraction of the subsamples I decided to:

1. extract a hundred vectors of length m containing random
   numbers from the sequence (1:r)
2. store them into a matrix of size (m x 100)
3. use each vector of this matrix as identifiers to subsample 100 matrices from the original matrix H
4. Finally, store each matrix obtained by this subsample into an array whose third dimension will be 100.

```
H = matrix( , nrow=r, ncol=c) 
id = seq(1:r)
N_samples = 100
```

```
# Empty array and matrix of the random numbers
B = array( , c(m, c, N_samples))
h_sample = matrix( , nrow = m, ncol = N_samples)

# Extract random numbers from the sequence "id" without replacement
for(i in 1:N_samples){
  h_sample[,i] = sample(id, m, replace = F)
}

## Now I sample the rows from H according to the identifiers randomly extracted and stored in matrix h_sample, and place each submatrix into the B array

for(j in 1:N_samples){
  B[ , , j] = H[h_sample[ ,j], ]
}
```

## It returns me this error:

```
Error in B[, , i] = H[h_sample[, i], ] : incorrect number of subscripts
```

I know that the problem lies in the last line of the code, do you have some advice to deal with this error? Would you suggest alternative ways to solve this exercise?

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to use the base function `replicate`, which in this case will replicate the matrix sub-setting a specified amount of times and directly creates an array of the matrices.

```
r <- 100 # number of rows
c <- 50  # number of columns
m <- 10  # number of rows you want to extract 

# example matrix 
H = matrix(rnorm(r*c), nrow=r, ncol=c) 

arr <- replicate(100, {
   id <- sample(1:r,m, replace = FALSE) # if you want to sample rows without replacement
   H[id,]
})
dim(arr)
# [1]  10  50 100
```